# Unable to replacing Sightpackages in python

Tags: python

My python version was 3.10 and I tryied to upgrade it to 3.11. But It couldn't do ssuccessfully.(python installer has no option to upgrade ).
So then uninstall 3.10 and download and installed ppython 3.11.
But then I face to another problem.It lost My python pip list ! But I save my sightpackages in another place.And I replaced the sightpackages to my new python sightpackages folder.
But when I type as 'pip list' in command prompt, its not appear my pip list.
Please help me to recover my sightpackages.

Comment: You need to install all packages again for the new python

Comment: Why it hasn't option to upgrade python version.